# Como resgatar um valor de inicialização de um plugin?

Tags: javascript

Vou expor o problema específico, mas eu sempre tive essa dúvida em um contexto geral: inicializei o plugin owl carousel. Tive a necessidade de implementar uma progress bar nele. Porém, eu preciso informar a velocidade de transição = o parâmetro autoplayTimeout pra progress bar durar o tempo correto. Segue o código:

```
var carousel = $('.owl-carousel');

carousel.owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  items: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayTimeout: 7000,
  onInitialized: startProgressBar,
  onTranslate: resetProgressBar,
  onTranslated: startProgressBar,
});

function startProgressBar() {      
  $(".slide-progress").css({
    width: "100%",
    transition: "width 7000ms linear"
  });
}

function resetProgressBar() {
  $(".slide-progress").css({
    width: 0,
    transition: "width 0s"
  });
}
```

Como eu conseguiria acessar o valor autoplayTimeout da variavel de inicialização do plugin e informar no transition: "width <*VALOR DE autoplayTimeout*> linear" da função startProgressBar()? 
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A sua variável "**carousel**" está definida em um contexto global, então acredito que ela possa ser usada normalmente dentro da sua função.

```
function startProgressBar() {      
  $(".slide-progress").css({
    width: "100%",
    transition: "width "+carousel.data('owlCarousel').autoplayTimeout+"ms linear"
  });
}
```

Se esse cara **carousel.data('owlCarousel').autoplayTimeout** retornar undefined ou disparar algum erro, tente usar **carousel.data('owlCarousel').settings.autoplayTimeout**. Depende da versão do plugin que você esta usando.

Comment: Muito obrigado Big Boss. Sua resposta me fez avançar. Consegui acessar com a seguinte sintaxe: carousel.data('owl.carousel').settings.autoplayTimeout.
Fui investingando com console.log...
Porém quando coloco isso concatenado a string da propriedade transition  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined" não entendo muito bem os "pormenores" do js, mas acho que esse valor não existe quando eu triggo o onInitialized. Continuo na busca.

Comment: A funcao startProgressBar, deve ser chamada após a inicialização do plugin (carousel), se não ele não vai ter nada para ler. A onde que você esta chamando esta função?

Comment: logo abaixo da inicialização do plugin, se vc ver na pergunta, a função é chamada no evento onInitialized, fornecido pelo próprio plugin

Comment: @user7069 neste caso, talvez funcione substituindo o "carousel.data('owlCarousel')" pelo this (depende do contexto).